# How do I integrate my own python .py file into my Clojure script using libpython-clj?

Tags: python, clojure, interop

It may be a stupid noob question, but I am a total beginner, so I would appreciate any help.
I spent over an hour searching through youtube and google for tutorials, but libpython-clj doesn't have much info out there.
In the examples I found, the python libraries being imported are from independent repos. I looked through the libpython-clj's readme and Gigasquid's tutorial, but I am totally lost.

How do I use my own python file?

Suppose I have a project with foo.py.
How do I integrate it with my Clojure script using libpython-clj?

I would be very grateful for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a try today because I was also curious about it too, so I created a small Clojure project to call a simple python package. The idea is that you can build trivial packages from your own Python code, install them in a virtualenv directory and use them from Clojure.

https://github.com/dfuenzalida/clj-python-interop

**EDIT**: I noticed that projects using libpython-clj are now using the clj tool with deps.edn and it works as expected. I've updated the repo above with a fully working example.